Prisma Supabase connection not responding
I'm trying to use Prisma on an M1 Mac, the command seems to not respond after running the command  npx prisma migrate dev --name init
This is how my schema looks like
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider  = "postgresql"
  url       = env("DATABASE_URL")
  directUrl = env("DIRECT_URL")
}

model User {
  id     String  @id @default(cuid())
  email  String  @unique
  name   String?
  habits Habit[]
}



Anyone please help.
npx prisma migrate dev --name init

Environment variables loaded from .env
Prisma schema loaded from prisma/schema.prisma
Datasource "db": PostgreSQL database "postgres", schema "public" at "aws-0-us-east-1.pooler.supabase.com:6543"


I get this whenever I Ctrl+C out of the process.
^CError: Schema engine error:


